# How to sort an IList in ascending or descending order Selenium C#

Tags: c#, sorting, selenium

I am using an IList to store IWebElements in them. Here is the code.

```
IList<IWebElement> tableColumnData = DriverContext.Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//span[text()='EnterpriseId']/following-sibling::tbody"));
Console.WriteLine("COUNT : " + tableColumnData.Count);
```

The issue is how do I sort this IList tableColumnData  in ascending or descending order. Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: Try This `tableColumnData.OrderBy(t=>t.Text).ToList();` and let me know if working

Comment: and how do i print the values after sorting?

Comment: Iterate the list using foreach loop after sorting

Comment: does work, it still gives me the original list, not sorted 

tableColumnData.OrderBy(t => t.Text).ToList();
            foreach (IWebElement element in tableColumnData)
            {
                text[i++] = element.Text;
                Console.WriteLine(text[i - 1]);
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the result of `OrderBy` to another list, it doesn't affect the list you call it on. Like so:

```
var sortedList = tableColumnData.OrderBy(t => t.Text); 
foreach (IWebElement element in sortedList) 
{
  Console.WriteLine(element.Text); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use a LINQ query :

```
var myOrdredList= from item in tableColumnData
                  orderby someProperty ascending //or descending
                  select item;
```

Comment: how do i set the property?

Comment: It depends on how you want to sort the table, let's say you want to sort it by the rang of the row, or by some id, then the 'someProperty' should be replaced by item.id or item.range.